# javascript get texts from element to array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, dom

I'm having trouble with getting texts that are in element to array. The structure I'm trying to 'extract' is looking something like this:

```
<div>
    text text text text
    <h2> title </h2>
    text2 text2 text2
    <img>
    <br>
    <br>
    text3 text3 text3 
    <h2> title 2</h2>
    text4 text4 text4
</div>
```

the result I'm looking for is array:

```
['text text text', 'text2 text2 text2', 'text3 text3 text3', 'text4 text4 text4']
```

I can't edit the HTML structure. And I don't have idea how to get this data to an array. I've only tried .text() from jquery, but that's not the way, and I didn't found anything in google, that would help.

Comment: Thanks for the information on what you're doing. I'm assuming you have a problem though. Please enlighten us with the problem :-p

Comment: Put your text into a tag like <span>text text text</span> then something like var array = $("span").split(" ");

Comment: Do you have control over the generated `html` elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [.contents()](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) and [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/) to create a solution

```
var arr = $('div').contents().map(function () {
    if (this.nodeType == 3) {
        var text = $.trim(this.nodeValue);
        if (text != '') {
            return text
        }
    }
}).get();

console.log(arr)
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/GLt7k/)